# Get the most recent "event" for distinct items using an SQL query (MySQL database)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of "events" that I'm using to store some statistical data on lab computer logins, logouts, shutdowns and startups.

What I'm looking to produce is a list of the *last* actions *each individual* computername did.

Here's a sample of what my table named **raw** looks like:

```
mysql> select * from raw limit 20;
+--------+--------------+-------+---------------------+
| id     | computername | event | timestamp           |
+--------+--------------+-------+---------------------+
| 148776 | REF-18       |     1 | 2014-11-05 15:05:29 |
| 148775 | DEC-02       |     3 | 2014-11-05 15:05:19 |
| 148774 | GPS-06       |     3 | 2014-11-05 15:05:18 |
| 148773 | DEC-15       |     3 | 2014-11-05 15:05:16 |
| 148772 | DEC-02       |     1 | 2014-11-05 15:04:33 |
| 148771 | REF-18       |     2 | 2014-11-05 15:04:18 |
| 148770 | REF-09       |     1 | 2014-11-05 15:04:14 |
| 148769 | REF-18       |     4 | 2014-11-05 15:04:02 |
| 148768 | DEC-02       |     2 | 2014-11-05 15:03:39 |
| 148767 | DEC-02       |     4 | 2014-11-05 15:03:24 |
| 148766 | REF-09       |     2 | 2014-11-05 15:03:00 |
| 148765 | DEC-08       |     3 | 2014-11-05 15:02:54 |
| 148764 | REF-09       |     4 | 2014-11-05 15:02:44 |
| 148763 | REF-09       |     3 | 2014-11-05 15:01:31 |
| 148762 | DEC-01       |     1 | 2014-11-05 15:01:13 |
| 148760 | REF-19       |     1 | 2014-11-05 15:00:50 |
| 148761 | DEC-04       |     3 | 2014-11-05 15:00:50 |
| 148759 | REF-18       |     3 | 2014-11-05 15:00:25 |
| 148758 | DEC-36       |     1 | 2014-11-05 15:00:10 |
| 148757 | DEC-01       |     2 | 2014-11-05 15:00:09 |
+--------+--------------+-------+---------------------+
```

I've come up with a couple of solutions I think could work;

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.computername, r1.event, r1.timestamp
FROM raw r1 
JOIN (SELECT id, computername, event, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp 
      FROM raw GROUP BY computername) 
AS r2
ON r1.computername = r2.computername 
   AND r1.timestamp = r2.timestamp 
GROUP BY r1.computername;
```

This seems to do the job, but it takes **f o r e v e r**

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * from raw order by timestamp desc) row_result 
GROUP BY computername;
```

This takes considerably less time by far, and yet seems to produce the same results. Which is better? Is the second query simply a *hack* on the way that MySQL works? Could I optimize my data, or query somehow to produce quicker more reliable results?

Thanks!

Comment: Second query works only if you are very lucky on the timestamps.

Comment: When things take forever, post the results of `EXPLAIN` for your query to see how your query is executed. It's almost always a case of missing indexes and relentless table scans.

Comment: you should totes try to provide a sql fiddle (at least in my opinion) for questions such as this to make it easier on the would be answerers - since many of us likely end up doing it individually anyway.

Comment: Appropriately indexed, your first query should be very, very fast. It has the advantage of being documented, as opposed to the second query which, while popular with some here, is as you guessed an undocumented hack.

Comment: ... also, there appears to be no purpose including id and event within the subquery, nor in including the GROUP BY clause in the outer query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
select r.id, r.computername, r.event, r.timestamp
from raw r
inner join (
    select max(id) as id
    from raw
    group by computerName
) as maxEventPerComputer on r.id = maxEventPerComputer.Id
```

Granted it's very similar to your initial query, but you might get somewhat better results especially considering your id column is (likely) indexed where your date column might not be (i'd imagine).

But from what i understand mysql is less good with the subqueries in comparison to other RDBMSes... but hopefully this will help.

Comment: That is **LOADS** quicker... Thank you so much. This really seems to be the best solution. I really should have thought about the fact that I could just pull MAX(id) as it's an incriminating anyway.